# Elastic Search: use filter and should bool query

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I want to use elastic search to search through a large address database, and to make it like some other applications I start with the postcode first which is great to narrow down on the rest of the search query.

So with [Search::Elasticsearch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Search::Elasticsearch::Scroll)

I do

```
my $scroll = $e->scroll_helper(index => 'pdb', search_type => 'scan', size => 100,
    body => {
        query => {
            bool => { 
                filter => [
                    {match => { pcode => $postcode }},
                ],
                should => [
                    {match => { address => $keyword }},
                    {match => { name => $keyword }},
                ],
            }
        }
    }
);
```

However that just spits out everything for `$postcode` and regardless of what `$keyword` is the result set is not further reduced.

I need to have `$postcode` as a mandatory condition but also separately and in addition the other two fields to also be taken into account as a full text search. 
How should I do this (Im looking at the docs and might be interpreting json->perl hashrefs wrong so any suggestions welcome)

For a hypothetical example:
User enters `NW1 4AQ`,  The above query will immediately return, say, Albany Street and Portland Street, if the user queries `Portland` *and* that postcode, instead of getting both those results, I expect only Portland Street to be the result. Right now with the above It just keeps returning both entries.

Comment: Is it possible to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: A wordy hypothetical example added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following common sense I found that the following does what I want for the `bool` segment:

```
bool => { 
            must => [
                {match => { pcode => $postcode }},
            ],
            should => [
                {match => { address => $keyword }},
                {match => { name => $keyword }},
            ],
                minimum_should_match => 1,
        }
```

Having `minimum_should_match` as 1 (which is a counter rather than true/false), feels like it's inserting an `OR` in those `should`s

Answer (score 2):

Elastic doc says:

> "**By default, none of the should clauses are required to match**, with one exception: if there are no *must* clauses, then at least one should clause must match. Just as we can control the precision of the match query, we can control how many should clauses need to match by using the `minimum_should_match` parameter, either as an absolute number or as a percentage"

So the way to do it is through `minimum_should_match`. Just as you did. What you did means that either *address* or *name* must be matched.